# Cisco IOS version

Tags: cisco-ios

Current release: 15.0(2)SE4

Latest release: 15.2(2)SE6 ED

Recommended release: 15.0(2)SE6 ED

Two questions:

1. What does the 'SE' stand for in the IOS versions?
2. Where can I find Cisco release notes that speak about the limitations, caveats and restrictions of each release?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing the device, it's hard to say. "SE" will likely be a special branch specific to a device. (usually a switch, AP, etc.)

Comment: If you're in the Downloads section of Cisco's website, there should be a release notes link at the bottom of the page after selecting a code version for further information.

Comment: It's a switch 2960S, also could you post a link to what you are speaking about. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal place you'd find the release notes for is under the platform itself rather than the code release, though it depends and isn't consistent.  Some release notes are organized by software rather than platform.  ED means early deployment.

The release you're mentioning is probably a bugfix release for Cisco 3700 switches.  That information is here:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/15-0_2_se/release/notes/OL25302.html#pgfId-1077264

Typically, you'll look at the main release for the caveats, then follow the train down the bugfix releases.  Usually, a bug scrub is also helpful, e.g. searching the features you're deploying using the Cisco bugsearch tools to determine whether any of them are things you might be concerned about.

Your Cisco or VAR SEs can also assist in choosing the right release for your needs.

Comment: See that's the thing, I am looking for information specifically concerning SE4. Also it's a 2960S any further assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SE4 is usually, like Ricky Beam said, platform specific.  These letters often don't have meaning platform to platform, but the numbers are bugfix releases.

Here are the SE4 caveats: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/15-0_2_se/release/notes/OL25301.html#pgfId-1128989

If no new features are listed in the top of the release notes for that version, it's usually just a bugfix release.

Comment: And 3750 and 2960 share the same code release in this particular train that you're talking about.